# multiValueQueryStringParameters missing from lambda call

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I made a call to an API Gateway connected to a Lambda function. I was expecting to see `multiValueQueryStringParameters` as a key in the `event` input to my handler.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/support-for-multi-value-parameters-in-amazon-api-gateway/

Instead, I was seeing a comma delimited list in `queryStringParameters`

So for example, this call:

https://12324234234234.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dois_to_pmids?a=1&a=2&a=3

generates the following event entry:

"queryStringParameters": {"a": "1,2,3"}

I tried making everything a proxy integration, first be doing:

`GET /{proxy+}`

and then by doing:

`ANY /{proxy+}`

with no luck.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

What's going on?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue while trying to parse a query with commas https://github.com/calavera/query-map-rs/issues/1

Answer (score 5):

So after a bit of digging I discovered an option when setting up the integration to select a payload version (either 1 or 2). You can currently read about the payload version formats (sort of, details are a bit light) here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

The main takeaway from that link is that version 2 doesn't have `multiValueQueryStringParameters`, instead repeated parameters are concatenated together in a comma separated list (as observed).

Haven't tested how this works with values that have commas :/

Comment: Thanks for digging this up Jimbo, you've saved me the effort.